# How to extract date from the DATE type in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, extract

I have a problem where I need to know which things happened before 10th day of the month. I tried this, but it doesn't give the expected result. :(

```
SELECT *
FROM Birth_Day
WHERE DATE(Birth_Day) < 10;
```

It says that it's an empty set. but there are some entries.

Comment: Which month the current month ? or months in database ?

Comment: Month in database. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`dayofmonth`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) (or [`day`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day), which is a synonym of it):

```
SELECT * FROM Birth_Day WHERE DAYOFMONTH(Birth_Day) < 10;
```